# Would an MA in Communications and New Media improve my design career prospects?

Tags: education, work

I have a BA & MA in unrelated fields, a certificate in web design/UX/UI and a basic portfolio. I'd like to get a job as part of a design team for a startup or relatively successful company in a year or 2.

I'm open to any design-related positions, if I find the work to be interesting. Would completing an MA in Communications & New Media while interning a bit make it likely for an employer to hire me? Any other tips of what I can do?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be a bit more specific. Rather than say what type of job you don't want, tell us what type of job you do want.

Comment: Telling us which country you are from may also be helpful re. salaries and work conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think *anyone* here can accurately state whether *more* education would assist in creating job opportunities.

You can have all the education in the world, but if your portfolio is lacking, you may not get any employment offers.

The truth of the matter is *experience and a good portfolio* carry **a lot** more weight than *any* education.

All a Masters shows is you excel at acquiring formal education. That is a *far cry* from having honed skills and solid work ethics. If you can't show that education in applicable and tangible forms, it's not often worthwhile to employers in design fields. i.e. I can take a course in cabinet making... I may get very high marks in the course - "ace" the course. But if my craftsman skills are so poor I can't build a cabinet which remains standing, what good is the education when seeking cabinet making employment?

At some point, lack of any education is *not* the detrimental factor.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, as I browsed all sorts of design job opportunities on indeed.com, many of the companies required a degree in graphic design "or similar fields". I wonder if communications is a similar field...

Comment: Often the "degree" is more of a method to weed out the "wanna-bes". If you have proven work experience and a decent portfolio, the degree becomes unimportant VERY fast. I would not allow the posting of a degree requirement to deter me. And Communications is often seen as a tangent field. After al design is communication `:)`

Comment: Thanks again! I assume by "tangent" you mean "close; related" as opposed to "a completely different line of thought or action, as in 'he quickly went off on a tangent about wrestling.'" Correct?

Comment: Yes `:)` close, related... guess I could have chosen a better word there `:)`.

Comment: Could you advise me as to how to get experience? I am currently at a job in an unrelated field that I must continue at for another year or 2. Should I volunteer somewhere a few hours a week? Do people do that? Should I enroll in some online courses? Is that considered experience? Any other ideas?

Comment: Online courses are not considered experience. Schooling of *any* kind is schooling, not work experience. You can freelance part time on the side... finding clients can be difficult, bit start letting people know you're looking for work in whatever field you want to go into.